# Facing difficulty with Scaffloding concept in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am preparing 3 pages one is questions for Quiz,one is for questions page and another one is for Options.I used relationship concept in Quiz model i used the following code

```
var $hasMany = array('question');

}
?>
```

and in Question model i used the following code

```
<?php
class question extends AppModel {
 var $name='question';

 var $belongsTo = array(
 'quiz'=>array(
'className'=>'quiz',
'foreignKey'=>'quiz_id',
'conditions'=>null,
'fields'=>null
)
);
}
?>
```

and in Quizzes,Questions and Chapters controller, i added Scaffolding concept
    public $scaffold;

Now I got add Question page,add quiz page and add options page but the problem is all the fields are of textbox but for some fields i need radio buttons and drop down buttons and image type.Is there any way to change the field type from default text boxes to our required format using scaffolding or any other way...
Please help me out with this problem.
                 Thank you.

Comment: a) Dont use scaffold. Try to use bake to generate code. b) Mind your casing: question != Question (the latter is correct!) c) Use proper coding standards. Your code currently looks like a mess and not what PHP5 and CakePHP2.x code should look like. The documentation can help you. d) You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you are asking how to automatically change the form input types like textbox, radio, and dropdown in scaffolding/bake.  This answer is for the current version of CakePHP 2.5.

[CakePHP determines the form input type based on the database column data type](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements).
So, for fields with a database column of char, varchar, or other string, CakePHP will output a text box in the form.  If you change a column type to boolean, you will see a checkbox.

For radio buttons and drop-downs, CakePHP also needs to know the list of options to present on the form.  Your database column therefore needs to be a foreign key.  An example:

Let's pretend one of the Questions on your Quiz is "What country are you from?".  So you need a table that lists all Countries.  Then in the Question table you would have a column called country_id.  Remember to update your Questions and Country model with the hasOne / belongsTo relationship.  Then bake/scaffold will output a form input with a dropdown for selecting the Country.  To change this to a radio button list (and more configuration options) see [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs).